# How to get line number for native crash in Android?

Tags: android-ndk, addr2line

I have a native library and a backtrace from internal crash reporting tool that provides me exact addresses where the crash has occurred.

I used `addr2line` tool and found that it was our own native library where crash is occurring. However, I am just able to get function name in which the crash is occurring and not the exact line number since we ship library after stripping debug symbols.

I have access to unstripped `.so` of the same library where I can easily get line number. The only problem is I have to map the addresses in stripped library to corresponding addresses in unstripped library.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Have you tried using the [ndk-stack](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack) tool that comes with the NDK?

Comment: Yes. Not working. Also, I have just addresses because we are using an internal tool for reporting crashes. I used addr2line on stripped .so which points out a function in C++ code.